# Значение выражения-паразита "как бы"

Tags: значение-слов, смысл

Мне кажется, что помимо того, что его употребление выказывает неуверенность человека в своих словах, у этого выражения есть ещё одно значение: *"дело в том, что",* когда его ставят в начале фразы. Например:

> Ну как бы я пришёл, чтобы поговорить с тобой.

То есть неуверенность оно может выражать **и** в этом случае, но и такой смысл тоже имеется, на мой взгляд.

Согласны со мной?

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, слово-паразит *как бы* не говорит о неуверенности в сути слов человека, скорее - о черте характера человека. Оно же "паразит", значит, не несет смысловой нагрузки и используется для связи слов в предложении. Используют его, как говорят психологи, люди, не совсем уверенные в себе, боящиеся ответственности за сказанное, люди интеллигентные.

Кандидат филологических наук О. СЕВЕРСКАЯ в журнале «НАУКА И ЖИЗНЬ» пишет:

> Вообще-то, частица "как бы" должна относиться ко всему
> "условно-предположительному" в ситуации сравнения одного с другим -
> так это определяет словарь Ожегова-Шведовой. Вот, например, у Ф.
> Тютчева "весенний первый гром, как бы резвяся и играя, грохочет в небе
> голубом" - здесь все понятно, гром описан как расшалившийся ребенок...
> Но в разговорной речи многие из нас сталкиваются с формулировками
> вроде: "Я как бы хотел тебе позвонить, но потом как бы закрутился..."
> И тогда возникают сомнения: так все же хотел позвонить или выдает за
> действительное желаемое?
>
> Одна из постоянных слушательниц программы, которая идет на
> радиостанции "Эхо Москвы", призналась: "Я два года не была в России,
> сейчас мне так странно, особенно от молодежи, слышать слово "как бы".
> Оно означает "как будто бы". Но они говорят так: "Я как бы пошел (или
> пошла) на работу..."
>
> Получается не совсем "на работу"... То есть - якобы пошел на работу, а
> на самом деле... Не думаю, что человек сознательно ставит под сомнение
> правдивость своих слов или не понимает, что же с ним на самом деле
> происходит. И фраза звучит комически. В принципе, над такими
> "высказываниями" только и остается, что смеяться сквозь слезы, как это
> когда-то сделал В. Войнович в ответ на откровения одной актрисы:
> бедняжка сказала, что "вышла замуж и как бы счастлива", а писатель
> мысленно посоветовал ей... немедленно разводиться.
>
> В разговорной речи "как бы" указывает на неточность формулировки, в
> сущности - это вариация на тему "так сказать", которое тоже в свое
> время "вставляли через слово". Специалист по арго, жаргонам и сленгу,
> а также по всяким приходящим и уходящим "словечкам" В. Елистратов в
> эфире "Эха Москвы" объяснял распространение этого "как бы" не только
> характерной для современного человека философией ухода от
> ответственности за слова и дела, но и тем, что русский язык вообще не
> любит определенности: "Во сколько ты придешь?" - "Ну часов в семь". Мы
> никогда не скажем точно. Так же, как индусы, например. Вы знаете, если
> индусу сказать точно: "Приходи в семь", - это будет выглядеть
> нарушением прав человека. Ему надо дать люфт: туда-сюда полчаса.
> Немца, наоборот, оскорбишь, если не точно скажешь. Действительно, мы
> любим говорить "часов в семь", "где-то в районе семи", переставляем
> слова, чтобы получилось "человек пять", а не "пять человек" - вроде бы
> пять, но вдруг мы ошиблись?" "Русские вообще очень не любят точно
> определять значение слов, - считает В. Елистратов. - Слушают,
> например, выступление премьер-министра и не слушают, что он говорит, а
> стараются уловить настроение... нам нравится выявлять значение слов по
> ассоциациям, по общей образности. Думаю, "как бы" из этой же оперы,
> это наша ментальность". Кстати, однажды ученый провел эксперимент:
> попросил студентов-гуманитариев определить, что такое "дефолт". Так
> вот: 95 процентов ответили, что это... "как бы революционная
> ситуация"!
>
> В заметках "Ноблесс оближ. О нашем речевом поведении" В. Новиков
> ставит "как бы" рядом с неопределенным местоимением "некий" и задается
> вопросом: может быть, нашему языку просто не хватает артиклей, вот он
> и подыскивает эквивалент англо-франко-немецким an, un, ein? Или дело в
> том, что все мы - во власти эстетики, которая делает
> наивно-реалистическое восприятие любого события просто невозможным.
> "Наше время, - продолжает эту мысль В. Елистратов, - не любит
> решительных глаголов и оценочно-выразительных эпитетов. Могли бы прямо
> сказать, но почему-то боимся"...

"Дело в том, что" - такой же "паразит", тоже только для связки слов, смысла высказыванию не добавляет.

Comment: "Для связки слов" — но она часто необходима, эта связка.

Comment: Она необходима, когда уместна. Во фразе «дело в том, что» слово «дело» по сути означает «причина», то есть «причина в том, что». . Если  предстоит объяснение скрытых причин, то после указания на сложность их понимания такое объяснение может предваряться вступительной фразой: "Дело в том что...". Примеры: Казалось бы, причина явления в этом. Но не всё так просто: дело в том, что на это накладываются обстоятельства, которые мы пока не учитывали.
Если в развёрнутых пояснениях нет необходимости, то и вводной фразы не нужно.

Comment: -Зачем ты пришёл? - Я пришёл, чтобы поговорить с тобой. Никаких подробных разъяснений  нет, зачем вводная фраза? И "как бы"неуместно, и "дело в том, что" лишнее, а всякие излишества - нарушение качества хорошей речи.

Comment: Ну конечно, в этом случае "как бы" неуместно, я просто хотел сказать, что бывают и такие случаи, когда выражение необходимо. ;)

Answer (score 3):

В толковом словаре Ефремовой приводится целых *три* "нормальных" значения **как бы**.
https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Efremova-term-33653.htm

Однако неуместное, "паразитогенное" употребление не только этого, но и некоторых других выражений, при внимательном рассмотрении позволяет выявить именно *неуверенность* говорящего. Факт употребления выражения "как бы" ещё не делает его *выражением-паразитом*: оно вполне "словарно" и имеет несколько полезных смысловых значений - как и некоторые другие выражения ("**это самое**", "**в том числе**" и т. п.), которые при неумелом употреблении становятся выражениями-паразитами. Да, выражение "как бы" (в английском - аналоги 'like' и 'you know') в середине 90-х многими вставлялось перед глаголом без особых смысловых причин, из подсознательной мнимой  вежливости (да, может восприниматься и как неуверенность говорящего). В наши дни "вежливость" сменилась своей противоположностью, элементом агрессивной риторики: вставленный предлог "в том числе" зачастую не выполняет обычной присоединительной функции (см. словарь Ефремовой по правильному употреблению "в том числе") и либо не означает ничего (становясь "паразитом"), либо путается с выражением "в частности". В "паразитическом" же случае употребления легко отбрасываемое "в том числе" смутно выражает якобы имеющийся у говорящего запас неиспользованных аргументов (на случай, если собеседник усомнится), что в действительности отражает *неуверенность* говорящего в убедительности своих слов.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! А какое употребление "это самое" вы считаете нормальным? Как член предложение, например "это самое пальто", или не только? Я просто сам грешу тем, что вставляю это выражение, когда чувствую неуверенность в себе. :)

Comment: Интересно увидеть примеры где "как бы" может напрямую заменяться на "как если бы". 2-ое значение из словаря. Пока сомневаюсь в таком.

Comment: @Артём Луговой "_Это самое_ [+ что-то среднего рода]" вполне нормально при ссылке на что-то уже упомянутое ("пальто" тоже может подойти). Типичный пример: " А в _это самое_ время..." Кроме того, возможны простые стечения указательного местоимения и прилагательного превосходной степени (_это самое_ большое озеро).

Comment: @user190920 Такие примеры возможны, хотя в словарной статье и не указывается на возможность прямой замены. _Он лежал неподвижно, с закрытыми глазами - как бы (= как если бы) спал._

Comment: Проблема в том, что "как бы" в значении "как если бы" исключает возможность по-настоящему "спать".  В то время как "как бы" в значении "как будто" допускает такую возможность. Получается противоречие у значений "как бы" в одном и том же предложении. Я конечно понимаю что "Да" может значить "нет" в зависимости от контекста. Но в словарях же не пишут: "Да" 2-ое значение - "Нет". А здесь вот решили написать...

Comment: Ну в таких случаях, конечно, это не слово-паразит, Александр, я это понимал. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Люблю грозу в начале мая,

Когда весенний, первый гром,

**Как бы резвяся и играя,**

Грохочет в небе голубом.

Автор: Ф. И. Тютчев. Давно это было, еще в 1828 году. Тогда «как бы» было всего лишь **метафорой, уподоблением, художественным приемом.** Мир в те времена был реальным, настоящим, устойчивым. А теперь мы все ближе к виртуальности, да и  вселенную нашу уже считают голограммой (трехмерной лазерной фотографией), поэтому  там всё **«как бы, вроде, где-то и типа».**  Мы вроде соглашаемся, как бы звоним друзьям, типа встречаемся, как бы дружим.

**Как бы – это символ нашего времени,** и очень странно, что его называют междометием, просторечием, словом-паразитом, молодежным жаргоном. Все перечисленные выше слова **довольно устойчиво вошли в нашу речь,** они уже не кажутся кратковременной модой.

На самом деле мы выражаем именно **виртуальность**, да и вообще скоро наденем специальные шлемы и окончательно перестанем отличать реальное от нарисованного.

Вот еще интересные высказывания о сочетании «как бы».

(1) По мнению лингвиста Ирины Левонтиной, часто встречающееся в речи москвичей «как бы» стало **словом-паразитом в 1970-1980-е годы.** Злоупотреблять им начали столичные интеллигенты, поклонники **великого писателя Ф. М. Достоевского.** В его творчестве **зыбкость и эфемерность реальности** подчеркивается частым использованием лексической формы «как бы». А после начала перестройки это слово-паразит подхватили представители всех слоев общества.

(2) Что такое «как бы»? В моём рейтинге (слов-паразитов) эта фраза лидирует. Даже не так. **Со всеми почестями побеждает.** От кого только её не слышу! Чего греха таить, у меня тоже это выражение нет-нет и проскочит. Хотя если и произнесу его, **то намеренно, в шутку.** (Ну да, как бы в шутку.)

(3) Однако, несмотря на «запятнанную репутацию», слово «как бы» входит в состав **современного литературного языка,** его оправданное употребление не является нарушением литературной нормы.

Так что слово "как бы" можно называть по-всякому, однако у него есть законные основания для присутствия в языке.

Comment: Ну нет, я конечно понимал, что у него есть нормальные значения!)

Comment: Артем, мы все это хорошо понимаем, но именно поэтому грань между нормативным употреблением слова и его сленговым значением очень размытая. Словечко незаметно проскальзывет в нашей речи - где нужно и где не нужно, мы к нему привыкли.  Мне кажется, что мы уже все так говорим, уже не замечая  этого. Сначала - как бы в шутку,  а потом и не в шутку тоже.

Comment: Нет, я не говорю)) Моя речь может быть испорчена другими словами по разным причинам, но этого я почему-то не говорю))

Answer (score 0):

Слова-паразиты не имеют смысла по определению. Из "Словаря-справочника лингвистических терминов"<sup>1</sup>:

> **Слова-паразиты** Слова или словосочетания, вносимые в речь, но не несущие никакой смысловой нагрузки.

Иногда они могут быть свидетельством неуверенности говорящего, но это не является их *значением*.

Кроме того, то или иное слово-паразит вовсе не обязательно показывает неуверенность. Слова-паразиты в первую очередь восполняют паузы, свидетельствуют о том, что говорящий ещё не закончил фразу и "просит" его не перебивать.

Сочетание *как бы* может добавлять фразе значение неуверенности, но в этом случае оно не является словом-паразитом, а является союзом или частицей (в зависимости от конкретного употребления).

*Дело в том, что* — это фразеологизм, который иногда тоже может быть паразитом. И в этом случае он будет иметь ту же функцию, что и паразит *как бы*.

Но, в случае использования по назначению, эти выражения не имеют какой-либо синонимии: *как бы* придает значение условности и предположительности; *дело в том, что* предваряет сообщение сути передаваемой информации.

---

1. Розенталь Д. Э., Теленкова М. А. Словарь-справочник лингвистических терминов. 3-е изд. — М., 1985.